# Plist sort by name in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, plist

Is there a way to sort a plist in Xcode by name?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>


    <key>Alpha</key>
    <string>This is the letter alpha</string>
    <key>Beta</key>
    <string>This is the letter beta</string>
```

etc...

I got this plist but xcode refuses to display the plist in order....

any ideas?